# Compare similar values within a table in power BI

Tags: powerbi, fuzzy-comparison, compare-attribute

I have fields within a table with values originally filled in by hand. Even if the same values are entered/meant, there can be "slight" deviations. Now I want to compare whether values in 2 columns within a row are quite similar.

If there is some similarity, I would like to have a True in a new column, otherwise a False. The use case is similar to the fuzzy join when two tables are merged, but the fields are within a table and do not work as a primary key. I have created a table below of what this should look like:

| No | ​A header | Another header | Calculated Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Zürich, 1.OG Telefonzentrale | Telefonzentrale | True |
| 2 | Mittelterrasse 1.OG Raum T190 | Mittelterrasse T1 | True |
| 1 | TM-Raum 225 | Bern, Bollwerk 10 / 2.OG | False |
| 2 | G7803 | 91G7803 | True |

It would be great if someone could help me in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is there a way to do this, but we can try to verify how many word from column1 appear in column2:

```
CheckIfTrue__ = 
VAR SplitByCharacter = " "
VAR Org = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet3[​A header])
VAR CurrentF = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet3[Another header] )
VAR Table0 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", Org),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, MAX(TokenCount,1) )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word])

VAR Table1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", CurrentF),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, MAX(TokenCount,1) )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word])
RETURN
   COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(Table0, Table1))+0
```

[image]